# how to replace strings in file based on values from another file? (example inside)

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

how to replace strings in file, based on values from another file.

Example, 2 files - input, output

input:

```
12345 1
```

output:

```
(1,'a lot of text', 'some other info',0,null, 12345),
(2,'a lot of text', 'some other info',0,null, 12345),
(3,'a lot of text', 'some other info',0,null, 12345),
(4,'a lot of text', 'some other info',0,null, 12345),
(5,'a lot of text', 'some other info',0,null, 12345);
```

Needs to be done:

read values from file 'input', and replace all '12345' with '1' in file 'output'.
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
sed `sed 's|\(.*\) \(.*\)|s/\1/\2/|' input` output
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to have AWK repeatedly call `sed`. Just have AWK read the first file into an array:

```
awk -F "[ )]" 'NR == FNR {a[$1] = $2; next} {sub($(NF-1), a[$(NF-1)]); print}' key-value-file main-file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat input | while read src rep
do
  sed -i "s, $src), $rep),g" output
done
```

Remember to make a backup of "output".

EDIT: Also note that if "input" contains characters that are *special* to sed, this will fail. For plain letters/digits it'll work fine.

Comment: Also consider `perl -pe` as a general purpose, more powerful `sed`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd found solution like you suggested, but I couldn't use it because of error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Answer (score 0):

ok, I came across this solution:

```
cat input | awk '{ cmd = "sed s/," $1 ",/," $2 ",/g" " output > output.new"; print system(cmd) }'
```

Comment: No need for the `cat`; just give the file to `awk`.