# Replace key:value from one file in another file in shellscript?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a "database file" with key-value entries and I have another file where the keys appear among other content. Now I want to replace that keywords with the values of my key-value file. Example:

There is one file "keys.txt" with "keyword space url":

```
name1 https://maps.google.com
something http://www.domain.com/bla.php?value=500
blabla http://thisis.example.com/moooooar.asp
```

I have another file "text.txt" which has one or several words per line, like this:

```
notrelated somewhatrelated blabla
blabla unimportant
asdf asdf asdf name1 dadadada
```

And as a result I want to have something like this:

```
notrelated somewhatrelated http://thisis.example.com/moooooar.asp
http://thisis.example.com/moooooar.asp unimportant
asdf asdf asdf https://maps.google.com dadadada
```

Actually my question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283653/ but non of the solutions mentioned there did work out since I am working with URLs (slashes, colons...) I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {url[$1]=$2; next} 
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in url) $i=url[$i]; print}
' keys.txt text.txt
```

```sh
notrelated somewhatrelated http://thisis.example.com/moooooar.asp
http://thisis.example.com/moooooar.asp unimportant
asdf asdf asdf https://maps.google.com dadadada
```

Comment: woaa! too fast! I can't compete against that ;)

Comment: could you please quickly explain what `NR==FNR {url[$1]=$2; next}` exactly does, I can't get it.

Comment: I know! ;) - It makes sure the first command-block is only run for the first file (`keys.txt`). `NR` is input-record counter for all files combined, `FNR` is input-record counter per file (resets for each file). They will only be equal when processing the first file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this works (but will probably break if you have commas in your keys):

```
while read k v; do sed -e "s,$k,$v,g" -i text.txt; done < keys.txt
```

Comment: how to make it work even for commas?

Comment: @RoobalJindal It doesn't work for commas because comma is used as "field delimiter" for sed. If you use a different character, comma will work (...but not the chosen character). Pick a character you know is not present in your data and replace the commas in the sed command with whatever you choose.