# Substitute values in a file using lookup file in Shell

Tags: shell

I have a lookup file with contents

```
A,B
C,D
E,F
```

and another file.
I wish to replace all occurrences of A in the another file with B, C with D, E with F and so on ( looking at lookup file) in Shell Script.

Its the same like [Replace key:value from one file in another file in shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416189/replace-keyvalue-from-one-file-in-another-file-in-shellscript)
but the solution isnt working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{k[$1]=$2;next}
         {for(x in k)gsub(x,k[x]);print}' lookup.file targetfile
```

This may not work if you have this in your "lookup file":

```
A,foo
foo,bar
bar,blah
```

or

```
a.*, B
b-$, foo
```

code wasn't tested, give it a try.